# Can I convert .ifo files with Final Cut?

Tags: macos, file

I need to convert .ifo files to upload to YouTube. I don't know how to determine what they are and how to convert / open them with Final Cut.

Is this common knowledge to someone or how might I figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) is able to open `.ifo` files, it also can save files in other formats:

- Open VLC
- Select File->Convert/Stream (or press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-S</kbd>)
- Drag&drop your `.ifo` file into the window
- Select conversion profile suitable for YouTube
- Select target file and click on Go!

Answer (score 0):

.ifo files are usually files from [a DVD-Video file structure,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video) and they usually come with a bunch of .vob files. IFOs are useless without the corresponding VOBs which contain the actual videos.

Assuming you have the contents of a video DVD's VIDEO_TS folder (which will contain file names such as VTS_01_1.VOB, VTS_01_1.IFO, and similar), you can [download Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), drag the folder containing these files into Handbrake (or open them using Handbrake's "Folder" option), and convert them from DVD-Video, preferably to H.264 AVC (called x264 in Handbrake) in an MP4 (not MKV) container with AAC audio, which is compatible with basically everything today, including FCP7 and FCPX. The Handbrake website has plenty of documentation to help you get started.